# Storing latitude/longitude in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an NSManagedObject that has two **double** properties for latitude and longitude.  When creating the NSManagedObject subclass I check the "Use scalar values" checkbox.  The .h file declared the properties as this:

```
@property (nonatomic) double latitude;
@property (nonatomic) double longitude;
```

I am retrieving a latitude and longitude value from a web service and am setting them locally with the following:

```
double tempLatitude = [[location objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
double tempLongitude = [[location objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];
```

However, the application blows up with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I try to use the dynamically-created setter from the NSManagedObject subclass.

```
[newPlace setLatitude:tempLatitude];
```

I also tried to convert the tempLatitude and tempLongitude to NSNumber values, but the setter tells me that I'm **"Sending 'NSNumber *__strong' to paramter of incompatible type 'double'"**

How can I correctly transform the values I'm retrieving for storage in my Core Data object?  Or do I have create some kind of custom setter in my NSManagedObject subclass.

If this is a repeat question I apologize.  I've searched quite a bit and most of the answers stop at "just store lat/long as doubles" without going into detail about that.

**EDIT**
More code was requested.  I've got it spread out over a few files, but I consolidated a simple request down into my AppDelegate just for testing and it still blows up with EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I try to run this chunk.

NOTE: I'm just trying to keep an NSManagedObject in memory for now (this context is not pointing to the database.)

Here's my managed object header file:

**Place.h**

```
@interface Place : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic) double latitude;
@property (nonatomic) double longitude;

@end
```

**Place.m**

```
@implementation Place

@dynamic name;
@dynamic latitude;
@dynamic longitude;

@end
```

Here's the lump of code that is setting up the context, creating an instance of the subclass, and trying to write a double value to it:

```
NSManagedObjectModel *model = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *memPsc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];

NSError *error = nil;

if (![memPsc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType
                          configuration:nil
                                    URL:nil
                                options:nil
                                  error:&error])
{
    [NSException raise:@"Open failed!" format:@"Reason: %@", [error localizedDescription]];
}

NSManagedObjectContext *memContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];

[memContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:memPsc];

Place *place = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Place" inManagedObjectContext:memContext];

double tempLatitude = [@"1.23" doubleValue];
double tempLongitude = [@"3.456" doubleValue];

[place setLatitude:tempLatitude];  // BLOWS UP HERE: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
[place setLongitude:tempLongitude];
```

Comment: try converting it to an NSNumber

Comment: I did that.  (See above.)  Once I have it as an NSNumber, the setter says it's an incompatible data type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scalar type in Managed Object only works for IPhone 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825895/scalar-type-in-managed-object-only-works-for-iphone-5)

Comment: If the header file is declared as doubles, why are you calling doubleValue on it?

Comment: `[newPlace setLatitude:someDouble]` or `newPlace.latitude = someDouble` should just work if "Use scalar values" was selected. No need to convert the doubles to NSNumber. Can you provide more information about the crash?

Comment: @Jeff he's not calling doubleValue on the Core Data attribute, but on the data he retrieved from a web service.

Comment: @Martin R Thank you for helping!  I'm going a little nuts here.  Here's the error I get when I just try to use the default setters: 

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0x375c8da0)`

Comment: But I can NSLog the values and they are there.  They're just not formatted correctly??

Comment: Perhaps show come code. How is the object created, how do you set the values?

Comment: @Martin R (and others) I added some code above. I'm really not trying to do anything crazy -- just setting a double value into an NSManagedObject. There's got to be something small that I am missing and I just don't know what that is.

Comment: I have no idea what is happening in your case. I can see no obvious error, and I could not reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just changing the properties of the NSManagedObject subclass to NSNumber and assigning NSNumber values to the objects.  It appears to have worked.  I wish I knew the "right" way to do it, if this isn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts"     inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSNumber *longitudesNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:longitudes];
NSNumber *latitudesNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:latitudes];
[newDevice setValue: longitudesNumber forKey:@"longitude"];
[newDevice setValue: latitudesNumber   forKey:@"latitude"];
```